# xxx.chunk.js return 422 (Unprocessable Entity) after app updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I am using CreateReactApp, the fact is that some users stay in old version app page after building and publishing of latest version app. And the user click for old xxx.chunk.js that not exist on host, then the error appear.

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const EducoderLogin = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./modules/login/XXX'),
    loading: Loading,
})
```

[image]

So how to captrue this 422 error, and refresh current page for the user.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this api to catch the error, works fine.
https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#loading-error-states